# Using Django, AJAX and JSONs to update charts based on user input

Tags: jquery, json, ajax, django, d3.js

Using Django I want to visualise data from my connected SQLite database. I have come to the point where I can query this data through Django views and visualise it in a d3 graph. Now I wish to allow a user to use a drop down list to customise their own queries, in this case allowing them to select a number which corresponds to a column of values in the database.

I used a JSON to create the drop down list, creating this JSON in a Django view based on a static query. Similarly I use a JSON to retrieve the data for the graph, this is where I have some difficulties.

#### The Issue

Although I get a JSON returned to my console, I wish to use it in d3.json() to display the values. This I wish to do by returning the json to a url and access that with d3. However I run into the following error:

```
GET http://127.0.0.1:8000/database/db_getselection/1416/ 500 (INTERNAL SERVER ERROR)
```

#### Template

```
<div class="BoxIt">
    <!-- Make a list of all ReportDataDictionaryIndex values, based on database table -->
    <div class="div-dropdown" style="height:25px;">
        <!-- Drop down list directly from database -->
        <select id="selected_variable" name="selected_variable"></select>
        <div id="results_selection"></div>
    </div>

    <h2>sel_var is: {{ sel_var }}</h2>
    <h2>variable_data_Te: {{ variable_data_Te }}</h2>

    <div class="div">
        <!-- Chart to visualise data -->
        <svg id="variable_data_plot" width="400" height="300"></svg>
    </div>
</div>
```

#### JS/jQuery

```
<script>
    $.getJSON('{% url "db_dictionaryindices" %}', function(options) {
        var select = document.getElementById("selected_variable");
        for (var i = 0; i < options.length; i++) {
            var opt = options[i].reportdatadictionaryindex;
            var el = document.createElement("option");
            el.textContent = opt;
            el.value = opt;
            select.appendChild(el);
        };

        $("#selected_variable").change(function () {
            var url = "/database/db_getselection/" + $("#selected_variable").val() +"/";
            var selected_var = $("#selected_variable").val();
            console.log(url);
            console.log("Selected variable: "+selected_var);
            console.log("selection is working!") // sanity check
            $.ajax({
                url: url,
                type: "POST",
                dataType: 'json',
                data: { selected_variable : selected_var },

                success: function(data){
                    console.log(data);
                    var post_data = data;
                    drawLineChart(post_data);

                    console.log("success"); // another sanity check
                    //$("#results_selection").html("<strong>Success: "+data+"</strong>");

                },
                error: function(xhr,errmsg,err) {
                    console.log(data);
                    $('#results_selection').html("<div class='alert-box alert radius' data-alert>Oops! We have encountered an error: "+errmsg+
                            " <a href='#' class='close'>&times;</a></div>"); // add the error to the dom
                    console.log(xhr.status + ": " + xhr.responseText); // provide a bit more info about the error to the console
                }
            });

            //Call this function within AJAX after the call returns a success
            function drawLineChart(post_data){

                    post_data.forEach(function (d) {
                        d.timeindex = +d.timeindex;
                        d.value = +d.value;


                        var vis = d3.select("#variable_data_plot"),
                                WIDTH = 400,
                                HEIGHT = 300,
                                MARGINS = {
                                    top: 20,
                                    right: 20,
                                    bottom: 20,
                                    left: 50
                                };

                        //d3.scale.linear uses two properties called range and domain to create the scale. Range defines the area avaiable to rende the graph, and Domain defines the min and max values.
                        var xScale = d3.scale.linear()
                                .range([MARGINS.left, WIDTH - MARGINS.right]).domain([0, d3.max(post_data, function (d) {
                                    return d.timeindex
                                })]);

                        var yScale = d3.scale.linear()
                                .range([HEIGHT - MARGINS.top, MARGINS.bottom]).domain([0, 50]);

                        //Create axis using scales defined
                        var xAxis = d3.svg.axis()
                                .scale(xScale);
                        //.orient("bottom");

                        var yAxis = d3.svg.axis()
                                .scale(yScale)
                                .orient("left");

                        vis.append("svg:g")
                                .attr("class", "x axis")
                                .attr("transform", "translate(0," + (HEIGHT - MARGINS.bottom) + ")")
                                .call(xAxis);

                        vis.append("svg:g")
                                .attr("class", "y axis")
                                .attr("transform", "translate(" + (MARGINS.left) + ",0)")
                            //.attr("y", 6)
                            //.attr("dy", ".71em")
                            //.style("text-anchor", "end")
                                .call(yAxis);

                        var line = d3.svg.line()
                                .x(function (d) {
                                    return xScale(d.timeindex);
                                })
                                .y(function (d) {
                                    return yScale(d.value);
                                });

                        vis.append("svg:path")
                                .attr('d', line(post_data))
                                .attr('stroke', 'green')
                                .attr('stroke-width', 2)
                                .attr('fill', 'none')
                                .attr("class", "line");
                    });

            };
        });
    });

    // acquire csrf token using jQuery
    function getCookie(name) {} // ETC...


</script>
```

#### database/views.py

```
def db_data(request):
    return render(request, 'database/database.html')

def db_getselection(request, sel_var):
    sel_var = request.POST.get('selected_variable')

    logr.debug(sel_var)
    variable_data_Te = Reportdata.objects.using('visdata').filter(reportdatadictionaryindex=sel_var).values("timeindex", "value")[:100]
    variable_data_Te = json.dumps(list(variable_data_Te), cls = DjangoJSONEncoder)

    return HttpResponse(variable_data_Te, content_type = 'application/json')

def db_dictionaryindices(request):
    DataDictionaryIndices = Reportdatadictionary.objects.using('visdata').values("reportdatadictionaryindex")[:15]
    DataDictionaryIndices = json.dumps(list(DataDictionaryIndices), cls = DjangoJSONEncoder)
    return HttpResponse(DataDictionaryIndices, content_type = 'application/json')
```

#### database/urls.py

```
urlpatterns = patterns('',
    url(r'^$', views.db_data, name='db_data'),
    url(r'^db_getselection/(?P<sel_var>\d+)/$', views.db_getselection, name='db_getselection'),
    url(r'^api/db_dictionaryindices/$', views.db_dictionaryindices, name='db_dictionaryindices'),
    ) + static(settings.STATIC_URL, document_root=settings.STATIC_ROOT)
```

Here an image of some data I got into the graph previously by setting a static value.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Month later, I figured it out and will answer my own question. Edited the question to be the working script.

Instead of trying to use d3.json and accessing a URL I could alternatively use call the function of the d3 graph directly within my AJAX success:

### AJAX

```
$.ajax({
    url: url,
    type: "POST",
    dataType: 'json',
    data: { selected_variable : selected_var },

    success: function(data){
        console.log(data);
        var post_data = data;
        drawLineChart(post_data);
    })}
```

Then instead of using d3.json as I orginally wanted to use, I use the data directly to create the graph:

### d3 graph

```
function drawLineChart(post_data){

    post_data.forEach(function (d) {
        d.timeindex = +d.timeindex;
        d.value = +d.value;

    //ETC
    )}
}
```

### Result

[image]

If anyone sees anything that could be more efficient or better, please let me know.